# What is the correct way to use cascade type when an entities refers to itself?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2, many-to-one

Assume that I have the following entity (Yes with lombok):

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Table(name = "entry")
@Entity
public class EntryEntity {
    @Id
    int id;

    String name;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    EntryEntity entity;
}
```

That entity represents some linked tree, that children entries refer to their parents. I assume that 1 child has 1 parent entity. For example, I want to save 2 entries in different transaction:

1. `EntryEntity child1 = new EntryEntity(2, "child1", new EntryEntity(1, "parent", null));`
2. `EntryEntity child2 = new EntryEntity(3, "child2", new EntryEntity(1, "parent", null));`.

`child1` and `child2` refer to the one entry `parent`.

I use H2 database with jakarta annotations with Hibernate Implementation.

When I try to save 2 children in different transactions, I receive the error: `Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.ENTRY(ID) ( /* key:1 */ 1, 'root', NULL)"`. Hibernate try to save twice `parent` entry.

Should I refuse to use cascade saving in that way or do I need to configure hibernate somehow in order to fix my problem?

Comment: You don't want the parent persisted. Your issue is when you persist the child, your cascade setting tells JPA to also persist the parent - the specification requires an exception to be thrown if you persist an existing entity. So if all your children will only be associated to existing parents and you don't want to do the work to read in the parent and have it use the managed parent reference, don't use cascade persist.